# requesting specific ubuntu versions in a docker container

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, docker

I started using Docker about two months ago and with some help got a container running ubuntu with Ruby 1.9.1.  This is the first portion of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Add and update apt sources
RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y upgrade

# Add compiler package and ruby1.9.1
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential ruby1.9.1-dev
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y npm
```

Recently a friend of mine wanted to use the same container but when he tries to build an image using that dockerfile he gets a message stating `'Package 'ruby1.9.1-dev' has no installation candidate'`, which I think means that he's actually pulling a different ubuntu instance from me (14.04 vs 12, something along those lines.)

I tried a search on the docker hub for an ubuntu image with ruby 1.9 on it and saw a couple of candidates but it wasn't clear to me whether they would work-- probably my own lack of understanding, there.

Can I tell docker which version of ubuntu I want to use, and / or is there a better way to accomplish what we're after?  Unfortunately I can't use Ruby 2.3 as there are some incompatibilities with one of the gems I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a version as a tag in the `FROM` instruction as so:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
```

for more information look [the FROM documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/from) and [the ubuntu docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also install a specific version of ruby on ubuntu in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get -y install ruby <version-number>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not likely to happen because the base image is the same, thus they should behave the same regarding repos and etc. Either you or your friend could have a different ubuntu image cached and named as ubuntu.

Try removing such images and pulling them again from docker hub:

```
docker rmi ubuntu
docker rmi ubuntu:latest
docker pull ubuntu
```

and then, try to rebuild.